# MacOS gives zsh: command not found: flutter after updating path according to Flutter

Tags: flutter, macos

Recently I updated Mac OS to latest Catalina and my terminal which is using zsh now start showing me following error:

```
zsh: command not found: flutter
```

It was working fine before update

Comment: This might be more appropriate in [apple.se]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suggest using FVM (Flutter Version Management). Which is a great tool, that can be used to install and switch between Flutter versions easily.

https://fvm.app

Concerning zsh, you could create a file named `~/.zshenv` where you can configure path variables. It works a bit differently than with bash.

```bash
#!/bin/zsh

# makes path an array with unique elements
typeset -U path

# adds flutter to the path
path+=('/Users/XXX/Tools/FVM/default/bin')

# adds global dart packages to the path
path+=('/Users/XXX/.pub-cache/bin')

export PATH
```

As you can see, I use Flutter with FVM, but you can of course just download Flutter yourself and provide the path in the `.zshenv` file. After changing the file you may want to run `source ~/.zshenv`, to make the changes available in the running terminal session.